# Does FIFA 12 support 4 gamepads?

Tags: fifa-12

I plan to connect 4 XBox 360 controllers to my PC and play this soccer game as local multiplayer.

Is this supported?

Comment: I am quite sure FIFA 12 does, but I never tried it myself. It definitely works on Xbox360 and PS3.

Comment: Questions that ask for a list of games that fulfil a certain criteria are considered off-topic in this site. See the [FAQ] for more information.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. I made some edits to not asking for a list of games.

Comment: Would you please reopen it?

Comment: Should be 2 separate questions.

Comment: Another edit - are you nitpickers now satisfied :D

Comment: @pixel - thank for correcting my spelling, but why did you delete the "local-multiplayer" tag?

Comment: @Mulmoth see [this thread](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/the-great-arqade-clean-up-of-2012) - we are in the process of cleaning up tags, the local multiplayer tag is one of those being edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to three controllers work fine, but the game crashes with the fourth one. It seems that the game does not support four controllers.